# What is a 'VOP' in MPEG-4 (RTP)?

Tags: definition, rtp, rfc, mpeg-4

I am reading through the MPEG-4 RTP Packet RFC (http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3016.txt) and finding very often the word

VOP

I have not found any definition in the net or RFC, does anyone can tell me what this VOP is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of video codecs, [VO](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~elgammal/classes/cs334/slide12_short.pdf) is usually *video object* and [VOP](http://www.globalspec.com/reference/34034/203279/9-1-video-object-plane-vop) is *video object plane*.